# Why my aspnet app is blocked until I press ctrl + c on its cmd window?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

After my aspnet core app is running for some time, suddenly it stops producing more logs on its cmd window. Only after I do `ctrl + c` on it, is that the program will continue working. I don't have any clues why would this happen.

Comment: It looks like a issue you can solve debugging your application with a debugger

Comment: This kind of behavior occurs when there are multiple concurrent requests, and it is hard to debug. A little theory is all I ask

Comment: it requires more details to troubleshoot the issue, we even don't know how it produce logs, so how can we figure out why it stops producing logs?